Why Is MongoDB Not Saving Full Data? Document Contains "..." Instead of Full Text
I’m working with MongoDB and noticed that some fields in my documents show "..." instead of the full text when viewed in the cloud.mongodb.com.
Have to add 'maxLength' in field?
const InfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
field1: { type: String, required: true },
userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' }, // Ensure this exists
// Add other fields as necessary
});

I've put in field and it still shows ....

Is that what's actually stored in the database or is it just the UI on MongoDB Cloud truncating the value when viewing it?

This code snipped is text schema and i don't know this is just a website stuff or really decreasing text in db.

Surely you can retrieve the document in your app and check? Or use the "Copy document" button in the Cloud website and paste the document to a text editor

You saying const document = await YourModel.findById('some-id') like this?

Hi @Luka: The issue you're describing, where fields in MongoDB documents show ... instead of the full text, is not caused by the MongoDB document itself or any restrictions on field lengths unless explicitly defined in your schema or code. Instead, this is typically a visual truncation issue with the MongoDB Atlas UI or the Mongo shell, which truncates long text fields for display purposes.
